# Delete single file from an old commit

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have just realized that an old commit committed a sensitive file that should not be in source control.

However, since that time there have been many branches and merges. If I go back to the original commit, then reset and re-do the commit, it will be a lot of mucking around to rebase and repeat all the branches and merges since.

The file has not been edited at all since its original commit; `git log badfile.ext` shows nothing other than that one commit.

Is there any other technique I can use to make the repository's history look like this file never existed, without changing all subsequent commits?

This is a private repo and so I know where all cloned copies are; it is OK if the problem can be fixed in one repo and then all other repos have to delete and re-clone to pick up the change.

Comment: You're asking to rewrite history.  That will change all subsequent commits, by definition.

Comment: @SLaks well I'm imagining something like manually editing the original commit but not changing its hash (and so the subsequent commits will not need editing, since they wouldnt mention the file since it had no changes).

Comment: No.  The hash of a commit is a hash of all changes files and its parent commit(s).  This is how git's history and integrity model works.

Answer (score 1):

See **Github's** docs on [removing sensible data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/). As mentioned here, you cannot do this without rewriting history (changing one commit means changing its hash, which in it's turn means that all the commits pointing to it must also change, and so on).

Also, keep in mind that it doesn't make sense (if even possible) to purge history on the clones as well.

So, basically you have to ask everyone involved in work with repo to push all their changes, then re-write history on your central repo, eliminate local clones and clone from the updated repository.